# Error trying to get attribute from element in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I have this HTML element:

```
<input id="" type="text" name="last_name" value="Userc7bff2d0-7faf-11e8-9884-8fe4c5df7f77-Updated" class="medium" maxlength="2000" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" data-reactid=".0.2.0.1.0.2.1.0.1.0.0.1:0.1.0.1.2:$/=10">
```

I want to get it's `value` property to assert that it has been updated by my test.

I have tried using `its()`:

```
cy
  .get(selector)
  .its("value")
  .should("contain", "-Updated");
```

But get the error:

> CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.its() errored because the property: 'value' does not exist on your subject.

I have also tried `invoke`:

```
cy
  .get(selector)
  .invoke("value")
  .should("contain", "-Updated");
```

But get a similar error:

> CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.invoke() errored because the property: 'value' does not exist on your subject.

In both cases, the Cypress console output of the get() command shows the element with its `value` property successfully:

> Yielded: input id="" type="text" name="first_name" value="Fake-Updated" 
>     class="medium" maxlength="2000" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" data- 
>     reactid=".0.2.0.1.0.2.1.0.1.0.0.1:0.1.0.0.2:$/=10"

I'm kind of stumped on this one.  Please let me know if you want more info or have an idea what's going on.

Comment: With some hacking about, I manage to get a working test with `cy.get('input').should('have.value', 'myValue')`. `cy.get()` returns an array of subjects (even if selector is specific and only returns one subject), so `its()` property references are properties of the array, not the subject. It would be better if cypress evaluated `its('myProperty')` consistent with the way `should()` evaluates its chainers.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[`invoke()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke.html#) calls a jquery function on the element. To get the value of an input, use the function `val()`:

```js
cy.get('input').invoke('val').should('contain', 'mytext')
```

This is **not** the same as getting the **value attribute** which will not update with user input, it only presets the value when the element renders. To get an attribute, you can use the jquery function `attr()`:

```js
cy.get('input').invoke('attr', 'placeholder').should('contain', 'username')
```

Comment: 'value attribute which will not update with user input' - this does not seem to be correct, according to my test. I'm doing `.type('newValue')` and seeing the value updated.

Comment: The actual dom attribute does not get updated. The value property does. Attribute !== Property

Comment: Yes, I figured that was what you were trying to say - that user update will not change the original value attribute (`Userc7bff2d0-7faf-11e8-9884-8fe4c5df7f77-Updated`). However, it should be noted for testing purposes value property **can** be used.

Comment: how to use `type()` after `should()`?

Answer (score 12):

you can use this

```
cy.get('a') // yields the element
  .should('have.attr', 'href') // yields the "href" attribute
  .and('equal', '/home') // checks the "href" value
```

or

```
cy.get('a').should('have.attr', 'href', '/home')
```

for more details check this:  https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Method-and-Value

Answer (score 7):

If above answers doesn't work try this,

```
cy.get('input[placeholder*="Name"]')
```

Find the input with a placeholder attribute containing the word "Name".

Answer (score 4):

Now there is a plugin for your need.

https://github.com/Lakitna/cypress-commands/blob/develop/docs/attribute.md

With this, you'll be able to do :

```js
cy.get('input').attribute('placeholder').should('contain', 'username');
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for sharing that, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Is this official tho? (≖_≖ )

Comment: Absolutely not. But sometimes a command or a plugin from a tier is cool too.

Answer (score 1):

Aprt from above suggestions, you can also get the value using `prop()`

The benefit of using `prop()` over `attr()` is that:
The `prop()` will always give you the current value but the attr can sometimes give you the default value no matter how many times you updated it.

```
cy
  .get(selector)
  .invoke("prop","value")
  .should("contain", "-Updated");
```

Answer (score 0):

#. Find attribute value in cypress - This covers the following things:

1. Find the attribute value.
2. Print the attribute value.
3. Compare two attributes value.
   Note:- For few attribute value do not capture due to HTML invisible rule. E.g.- viewBox="0 0 24 24".

cy.yourlocator.then(($label) => {

```
    let downloadReportBtnDataTablePath = $label.attr('d'); //d is attribute

    cy.log("DownloadReportBtnDataTablePath: " + downloadReportBtnDataTablePath) //Print the attribute value

    cy.yourlocator.then(($label) => {
      let exportHighChartReportBtnPath = $label.attr('d');
      cy.log("ExportHighChartReportBtnPath: " + exportHighChartReportBtnPath)

      expect(downloadReportBtnDataTablePath).equals(exportHighChartReportBtnPath); //Compare both attribute value. 
    })
  })
```

[image]