# How to get the value for data-id in cypress

Tags: jquery, attributes, cypress, invoke

I need to get the value for data-id but when I use the below code it does not return any.

```
cy.get('[data-nemo=token]')
  .invoke('attr', 'data-id').then(dataId => {
    cy.log('dataId : ', dataId);`enter code here`
  });
```

Thanks,

Comment: <div data-nemo="token" data-id="AAEWfkOxgu9yktVClhsDc0lRqWJguneYTcnnW6XYzBRwBfGag==">

Comment: Looks like an improper use of `invoke()`.  As far as I can tell from the documentation it should be something like `cy.get('[data-nemo=token]').getAttribute('data-id')`.  Related documentation: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Selector

Comment: getting error when using .getAttribute - 
TypeError: cy.get(...).getAttribute() is not a function

Comment: How many elements on the page match that selector?  If the `get()` returns an array like object, you will have to dig down into it some how to get the element to call `getAttribute` on

Comment: only 1 match for the given selector. Do I need to have any other plugins to use getAttribute func as it says its not supported

Comment: `getAttribute` is a native Element method.  So so long as you can get a native DOM Element out of the results of `get()` in some manner, you can use that method to get the attribute value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178736/error-trying-to-get-attribute-from-element-in-cypress  Woah, I may be completely wrong abou the `invoke()` thing.

Answer (score 7):

As per Cypress docs, you can use `cy.invoke` to call a jQuery method. So, just as in jQuery, you would do

```
$('[data-nemo=token]').data('id');
```

in Cypress it's

```
cy.get('[data-nemo=token]').invoke('data', 'id');
```

If you then want to use that value, you can either use `.then` or create an alias with `.as` and reference the alias later in your tests:

```
cy.get('[data-nemo=token]')
  .invoke('data', 'id')
  .then(dataId => cy.log('dataId : ', dataId));
```

or

```
cy.get('[data-nemo=token]')
  .invoke('data', 'id')
  .as('dataId');

cy.get('@dataId')
  .then(dataId => cy.log('dataId : ', dataId));
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the below code and see if that is working. Try using `data()` or `attr()` option to get id ;

```
cy.get('[data-nemo=token]').then(($div) => {
        const dataId = Cypress.$($div).attr("data-id");
            // or
        const dataID = Cypress.$($div).data("id");
           // or
        const mydataID = Cypress.$(this).attr("data-id");
        console.log(mydataID);
});
```

Comment: the above also did not work and I still don't get the value of 'data-id'

Comment: Please post the full html of that section, if that is nested inside of some other div please include from top/parent

Comment: I have updated my ans, just before the console log another approach, give another try..if not please post the full html of that section

Comment: thanks, but still its not working...I could not paste the entire html so breaking it

Comment: <div><div><div><form action="/authflow/iroute/" method="POST" id="irouteForm"><input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="m6BhEZ"><input type="hidden" name="anw_sid" value="AA"></form><div class="jsDisabled"><noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='/signin'" /><style nonce="Z7a6LBOc">html {display: none}</style></noscript></div><div class="contentContainer" id="content"><div data-nemo="twofactorPage" class="twofactorPage"><header><div class="logo"></div></header><div data-nemo="twofactorSelectedToken" data-id="AAFK3YP7">

Comment: <p class="heading">Enter your code</p><p class="description"><span>We sent a 6-digit code to xxxxxxxx029.</span></p><form novalidate=""><div><div class="input textInput"><div class="fieldWrapper"><label class="otpCodeLabel fieldLabel" for="otpCode"></label><input type="text" name="otpCode" value="" class="hasHelp" placeholder="Security Code" autocomplete="off" data-nemo="twofactorOTPInput" maxlength="6" id="otpCode" aria-describedby="otpCode"></div><div class="inputAction">

Comment: <div class="resend-link"><span class="resend">Resend</span></div></div><div class="inputTooltip errorMessage infoMessage"><ul></ul></div><div class="errorMessage" aria-hidden="true" role="alert" id="inputErrorMessage"><p class="emptyError" data-nemo="inputErrorMessage"> code should not be empty.</p></div></div><div class="vx_checkbox checkboxContainer"><input type="checkbox" name="skiptwofactor" value="" id="skipTwofactorCheckbox">

Comment: <label class="skiptwofactorlabel" for="skipTwofactorCheckbox">Don't ask for a code on this browser</label></div></div><button type="submit" data-nemo="twofactorSubmit" class="vx_btn vx_btn-block">Continue</button></form><a href="https://www.stage.com/auth/stepup?returnUri=h\&amp;stepupContext=twofactor&amp;flowContext=2fa" data-nemo="twofactorTryAnotherWayAuthflow" class="vx_anchor">Having trouble logging in?</a></div></div><div class="loaderOverlay"><div data-nemo="loaderOverlay" class="modal-animate hide"><div class="rotate"></div><div class="processing">Processing...

Comment: </div><div class="loaderOverlayAdditionalElements"></div></div><div class="modal-overlay hide"></div></div></div></div></div></div>

Comment: In the `html`  provided i am unable to find `data-nemo=token`.But I could see `data-nemo="twofactorSelectedToken"`, so which one is the correct data-nemo ?

Comment: sorry initially for sample code snippet I edited, I'm looking at data-nemo="twofactorSelectedToken" for which I need the data-id